# Como copiar banco SQLITE da memoria interna para o cartão SD comando Linux

Tags: android, linux, sqlite

Bom dia pessoal,
Certo dia consegui encontrar o banco de uma aplicação android que estou fazendo na memória interna via comandos Linux, a aplicação é em Delphi XE mas o local de armazenamento é o mesmo de uma aplicação desenvolvida no Eclipse.
Pois bem a o banco se encontra em /data/data/com.embarcadero.Meuapk/files/Meuapk.db3
e meu objetivo é copia - lo para o cartão de memória para que eu possa abri-lo com um SGBD.
Já tentei com cp mas ele não reconhece esse comando, será que há alguma forma ou o banco não pode ser copiado ?

Comment: Não consegue usar ADB? `adb pull /data/data/com.embarcadero.Meuapk/files/Meuapk.db3`? Lógico, assumindo que você tem o Android SDK na máquina.

Comment: Obrigado @g.carvalho97 com o auxilio da sua pergunta consegui fazer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na realidade copiei para o meu PC em vez do SDCARD assim consegui abrir ele com um SGBD.

Com o Auxilio do @g.carvalho97 consegui fazer da seguinte maneira:
Ativei a "Depuração USB" do tablet
Abri o CMD como administrador e fui até:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools

Chequei se meu dispositivo estava conectado com o comando adb device

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools**adb devices**

Usei o adb shell para navegar no android pelo terminal e depois fui até a pasta e dei permissões para ler, gravar, exluir (CHMOD 777)

Sai do root e voltei para Platform-tools, digitei :

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\PlatformSDKs\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools**adb pull /data/data/com.embarcadero.Meuapk/files/Meuapk.db3 c:/minhapasta**

Obrigado a todos