# Backup em banco de dados SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Preciso fazer um backup de um banco de dados SQLite do Android.

Ex: Vou trocar de aparelho e preciso copiar o BD do aplicativo para ser carregado no outro celular Android.

Existe alguma solução viável?

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que usa o SQLite para gravar informações, agora eu preciso fazer com que o usuário possa fazer um backup do banco para poder transferir para outro celular.

Comment: Não é uma duplicata de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33387/como-copiar-banco-sqlite-da-memoria-interna-para-o-cart%C3%A3o-sd-comando-linux/33481#33481?

Comment: eu preciso pra fazer backup pra todos que tem o aplicativo instalado!

Comment: Ah, não ficou claro isso na pergunta. Você pode usar o `BackupHelper` nesse caso: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupHelper.html

Comment: a dúvida dele acredito eu que seja como exportar o arquivo e como importar.

Comment: Tem uma boa ajuda, com código, neste post http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/export-sqlite-data-from-your-android-device/

Comment: como ele quer salvar o banco e transferir para outro celular, sem ele exportar para um arquivo e importar?
alem disso ele não deixou claro

Comment: seria isso mesmo, simplesmente exportar para o SD ou qualquer outra coisa, e depois importar novamente para que a aplicação possa carregar!

Comment: estou com o mesmo problema mas reeditaram a pergunta, então criei outra um pouco diferente
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38422/exportar-arquivos-do-sqlite-para-csv
@césar da uma olhada lá e ve se alguma coisa te ajuda

Answer (score 7):

A solução em baixo apresentada foi extraída de uma resposta no SOEN e faz o que pretendes, muito embora exista bastante margem para melhoramentos e melhor portabilidade:

## Importar

```
private void importDB() {
  try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<nome do package>" 
            + "//databases//" + "<nome da BD>";
        String backupDBPath = "<nome ficheiro backup da BD>"; // No SDCard
        File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
        src.close();
        dst.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Importação com sucesso!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Importação Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
  }
}
```

## Exportar

```
private void exportDB() {
  try {
      File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

      if (sd.canWrite()) {
          String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "<nome do package>"
              + "//databases//" + "<nome da BD>";
          String backupDBPath = "<destino>";
          File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
          File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

          FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
          FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
          dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
          src.close();
          dst.close();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup com sucesso!",
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Falhou!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();   
  }
}
```

---

<sup>Créditos da resposta para o utilizador @adefran83 [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18322762/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No caso do getApplicationContext(), será interessante você passar como parâmetro para o construtor da classe onde esses métodos ficarão o Context, por ele você pode acessar getApplicationContext().