# Exportar arquivos do SQLite para CSV

Tags: android

Preciso dar a opção para que usuário exporte uma desejada tabela do banco de dados para um arquivo no SD card, para que se torne pessoal e que ele possa importar em outro dispositivo depois.

Tenho uma aplicação onde eu trabalho com várias tabelas no banco de dados, essa aplicação é para usar junto com o equipamento onde você pode importar coisas, há uma grande chance de alugar o equipamento junto com um tablet.

A minha sacada é que ao cara importar seu modo de trabalho no equipamento, ele tenho junto com ele sua tabela de trabalho e ele importa no tablet para utilizar junto.

**Meu problema está em exportar somente a tabela desejada.**

Não acho documentação a respeito explicando, só algumas amostras de código que não funcionam, talvez pelo contexto.

Utilizei esses exemplos:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/export-sqlite-data-from-your-android-device/

http://www.tudosobretecnologia.com.br/2013/08/exportacao-de-dados-sqlite-do-seu.html

no final com muito custo fiz isso:

```
package com.example.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class exportararquivo extends ListActivity{


    SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
Cursor cursor;
List<Lista> tabelas = new ArrayList<Lista>();
String tabbanco="Tabela1";
TextView gerenciar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gerenciamento);
    gerenciar=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewgerenciar);
    gerenciar.setText("   Escolha a tabela que deseja trabalhar.");
    abrebanco();
    buscardados();
    List<Lista> lista = gerarlista();

    final Listaadapter listasadapter = new Listaadapter(this,  lista);
    setListAdapter(listasadapter); 


    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Lista tabela = listasadapter.getItem(position);
        exportDB(tabela.getNome());


        Intent intent = new Intent(exportararquivo.this, gerenciar.class);
        //intent.putExtra("tabbanco", tabela.getNome());
        exportararquivo.this.finish();
        startActivity(intent);


    }
    });

}

public List<Lista> gerarlista() {
    tabelas.add(criarLista("Tabela1"));
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int x=cursor.getCount();
    while(x>1){
    nextdado(); 
    tabelas.add(criarLista(retornadado())); 
    x--;
    };
    return tabelas;
}
public boolean nextdado(){
    try{
        cursor.moveToNext();
        return true;

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        return false;

    }
}
private Lista criarLista(String nome) {
    Lista tabelas = new Lista(nome);
    return tabelas;
}
public boolean buscardados(){
    try{
        cursor = Banco.query("tabela",
                new String [] {"tabelas",}
        , null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        }else{
            String sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (tabelas) " +
                      "values (Tabela1) ";
                Banco.execSQL(sql);
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao buscar no banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
        return false;
    }
}
public String retornadado(){
    String dado = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tabelas"));
    return dado;
}
public void abrebanco(){
    try{
        Banco = openOrCreateDatabase("banco", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
        String sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                ", tabelas TEXT)";
        Banco.execSQL(sql);

    }
    catch(Exception erro){
        Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao criar banco: =/"+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
    }
}

public void Exibirmensagem (String titulo, 
        String texto, String button)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(exportararquivo.this);
    mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
    mensagem.setMessage(texto);
    mensagem.setNeutralButton(button,null);
    mensagem.show();
}  







    private void exportDB(String tabela){
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
           FileChannel source=null;
           FileChannel destination=null;
           String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "Star_Lighting_Division" +"/databases/"+tabela;
           String backupDBPath = tabela;
           File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
           File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
           try {
                source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                source.close();
                destination.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

O problema é que isso não funciona e não consigo exportar nada...

estava tentando usar o exemplo do google http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage

mas n sei ainda como escrever um arquivo, não consigo nem mesmo criar ele

Comment: Acho que vale a pena deixar o usuário escolher qual pasta ele quer colocar (usando um `Directory Picker`) ou então usar o `Internal Storate` público, em vez de `External Storage` (o usuário pode não ter um SDCard) com (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) para dar oportunidade do usuário acessar por outro meio.

Comment: eu ja li essa literatura toda @wakim mas não consegui implementar, falta como editar o tal arquivo, 
vlw!
e sim sua ideia é super valida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso temos que ter em mente que o arquivo `.csv` tem uma divisão de campos simplificada.

Para trabalhar montando um arquivo desses, basta que você separe os campos com um **ponto e virgula** - `;`.

Qualquer leitor de arquivo `csv` interpreta por padrão o `;` como separador de campos, nesse caso basta você ler a tabela e escrevê-la num arquivo de texto e a cada campo escrito de cada registro você adiciona um `;`, depois de acabar com a linha (registro) que está escrevendo e for movendo o cursor, você adiciona uma quebra de linha no arquivo.

Para isso também é necessário que você adicione a permissão para escrever em memória externa no `Android.manifest` da sua App.

Você terá que utilizar também a classe `FileOutputStream` e `File`;

```
    public void escrever(){
    File caminho = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/arquivos");
    if (!caminho.exists())
        caminho.mkdir();

    File file = new File(caminho.getPath()+"/arquivo.csv");

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //aqui você pode adicionar o que desejar salvar usando estruturas de código e tudo mais
        String aux = "o que eu quero salvar;dividido por ponto e virgula\n"+
                    "e com quebra de texto";

        out.write(aux.getBytes(), 0, aux.getBytes().length);
        //esse método write deve ficar dentro da estrutura de repetição 

        //já essa parte de flush e close tem que ficar fora e 
        //deve ser executada apenas quando já tiver terminado de gerar todo o arquivo 
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Valeu @Chun pela formatação, ficou bem melhor de ler, fiz rápido e não prestei atenção nos detalhes, valeu mesmo